# Is nurse prescribing limited to PGD medication?

Tags: medications, nurse-practitioner

Are nurse prescribers limited to giving PGD medication only?

Or are there non-PGD medications they are permitted to prescribe?

This question relates to NHS general hospitals in the UK.

Comment: What’s PGD medication? You might want to spell out that abbreviation for non-UK’s who don’t know the abbreviations.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking in general what nurse practitioners are allowed to prescribe, which varies by country and region, or if you are specifically asking about just the UK system.